# What is the Time Complexity of $T(N)=2T(N/2)+\log n!$ and the answer does not have $\log n!$ in it?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

None of the 4 possible answers have $\log n!$ in them

e.g. one of them is $O(n\log n)$

I tried solving, but I can't get why there is no $\log n!$ in non of the answers?!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n

Comment: Hint: log n! is very close to n(log n - log e)